# Two devices on Arduino Uno R3 TX Pin

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm making the project using Arduino Uno R3 Platform. I want to use two devices, acc+gyro (MPU-6050) and Bluetooth (HC-06). The problem is, that both devices need TX Pin (2). Do you have any idea how to use this devices with Arduino Uno R3 at the same time? (I mean that I want to connect Bluetooth and MPU6050 to the same TX Pin) If it will help, I only need to send data to Arduino via bluetooth.

I found similar topic, but I'm not sure that the answer is correct:
[Similar Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794452/2-rx-and-2-tx-send-data-from-arduino-to-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Software Serial library.One you pin config your Bluetooth and other pins can configured for your gyro
[Example programs](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used those devices but if the issue is communicating with two serial devices from an Uno, you can use the [SoftwareSerial](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) lib. It emulates the UART which is on pins 0/1 on the Arduino. If you are using libs for those devices (or shields) which expect communication from TX pin 2, you will have to adjust the code.

But the [MPU-6060](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050) uses IC2 communication, not serial, so...? [Wire lib](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire)

Comment: Yes, I know and it is strange for me too, but I found the way which uses 2 Pin